# In Anspruch nehmen oder in Gebrauch nehmen

Tags: difference, word-choice, synonym

> **jemanden, etwas in Anspruch nehmen** (1. jemanden beanspruchen, von etwas Gebrauch machen: er nahm ihn, seine Hilfe gern in Anspruch. 2. erfordern, beanspruchen: der Beruf nimmt sie ganz in Anspruch; das nimmt alle meine Kräfte in Anspruch.)
>
> **etwas in Gebrauch nehmen** (etwas zu gebrauchen beginnen)

Quelle: Duden

Meine Theorie, worin der Unterschied liegt, ist, dass **in Gebrauch nehmen** bedeutet, dass man beginnt etwas zu gebrauchen, während **in Anspruch nehmen** sich auf den "andauernden" Gebrauch bezieht; d. h. **in Gebrauch nehmen** konzentriert sich auf *das Beginnen* und **in Anspruch nehmen** auf *das Gebrauchen*.

So würde ich aus den Definitionen folgern. Ist diese Theorie korrekt? Oder besteht der Unterschied in etwas anderem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Gebrauch nehmen heißt, dass man beginnt etwas zu benutzen, z. B. nimmt man eine Bohrmaschine in Gebrauch und bohrt ein Loch.

In Anspruch nehmen bezieht sich eher auf eine Leistung eines anderen. Man nimmt (um mal beim Beispiel der Bohrmaschine zu bleiben) die Hilfe eines Handwerkers in Anspruch (man nimmt keine Hilfe *in Gebrauch*), das Loch ordnungsgemäß zu bohren. Andere Beispiele wären: Man nimmt die Hilfe eines Steuerberaters in Anspruch oder man nimmt Sozialhilfeleistungen in Anspruch.

Answer (score 5):

Diese beiden Redewendungen unterscheiden sich in der Kernaussage stark. Ich will versuchen es auf den Punkt zu bringen, auch wenn es zunächst tautologisch klingt. "In Gebrauch nehmen" ist stets eine Handlung des Gebrauchens, "In Anspruch nehmen" dagegen eine des Beanspruchens. Anhand dieser Unterscheidung lässt sich schnell erkennen, dass man einen Mitarbeiter nicht "in Gebrauch nehmen" kann.

Wenn ich etwa einen Mitarbeiter "sehr in Anspruch nehme" liegt die Betonung darauf, dass ich einen starken Anspruch auf ihn geltend mache und seine Kapazitäten gebunden habe, welche nun zum Beispiel nicht mehr für andere Kunden zur Verfügung stehen.

Es ist im Grunde nicht wichtig ob es um Leistungen Dritter geht, wie es eine Antwort suggeriert. Richtig ist auch folgender Satz:

> Meine Arbeit nimmt mich stark in Anspruch.

Eventuell war es die Formulierung "Gebrauch machen" im Duden welche Sie verwirrt hat. Ich denke es sind solche Fälle gemeint:

> Er nahm sein Recht in Anspruch.

Dies lässt sich nämlich auch schreiben

> Er machte von seinem Recht Gebrauch.

In diesem Kontext kann man vielleicht eine kleine Gemeinsamkeit erkennen. Der Satz:

> Er nahm sein Recht in Anspruch.

könnte auch den Fall beschreiben wo man von einem bisher ungenutzten Recht Gebrauch macht.

Comment: In deinem Beispiel „Meine Arbeit nimmt mich stark in Anspruch.“
bist du quasi der Dritte aus Sicht der Arbeit.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde gern noch anfügen, daß *in Gebrauch nehmen* in der Alltagssprache meines Wissens nicht vorkommt; es könnte möglicherweise ein juristischer Ausdruck sein.

Was hingegen öfter vorkommt, ist *in Betrieb nehmen*. (Wenn es sich dabei um Flughäfen, Autobahnabschnitte oder dgl. handelt, erfolgt dies oft symbolisch durch Zerschneiden eines weißen Bandes durch einen Politiker). Es kann sich aber auch um weniger Spektakuläres handeln, wie eine neue Softwarelösung. Characteristischerweise gibt es das Subjektiv "die Inbetriebnahme" wohingegen "die Ingebrauchnahme" ihr Dasein im Reich des Ungesprochenen fristet.

Comment: Früher waren die Bänder doch noch rot oder golden …